# Ошибка Мессенджера

Tags: python

Здравствуйте Люди добрые!
Помогите, написал код для простого онлайн чата через библиотеку pywebio, но он не работает. После ввода имени выдаёт цыпочку ошибок.[image: Ошибка]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Богдан\Desktop\Chat alpha 1\Chat Alpha 1.venv\Lib\site-packages\pywebio\session\coroutinebased.py", line 325, in step
coro_yield = self.coro.send(result)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Богдан\Desktop\Chat alpha 1\Chat Alpha 1.venv\Lib\site-packages\pywebio\session\coroutinebased.py", line 101, in _start_main_task
await target()
File "C:\Users\Богдан\Desktop\Chat alpha 1\Chat Alpha 1\main.py", line 34, in main
actions(name="cmd", buttons=["Отправить", {'label:': "Выйти", 'type': 'cancel'}])
File "C:\Users\Богдан\Desktop\Chat alpha 1\Chat Alpha 1.venv\Lib\site-packages\pywebio\input.py", line 576, in actions
item_spec['buttons'] = _parse_action_buttons(buttons)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Богдан\Desktop\Chat alpha 1\Chat Alpha 1.venv\Lib\site-packages\pywebio\input.py", line 463, in _parse_action_buttons
assert 'label' in act, 'actions item must have label key'
AssertionError: actions item must have label key

При этом PyCharm ошибок в коде не нашёл.
Заранее огромное спасибо!

```
from pywebio import start_server
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import run_async, run_js

import asyncio

chat_msgs = []
online_users = set()

MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT = 100


async def main():
    global chat_msgs

    put_markdown("## Добро пожаловать в Чат(Alpha 1)")

    msg_box = output()
    put_scrollable(msg_box, height=300, keep_bottom=True)

    nickname = await input("Войти в чат", reguired=True, placeholder="Ваше имя",
                           validate=lambda n: "Такой ник уже есть" if n in online_users or n == "V" else None)
    online_users.add(nickname)

    chat_msgs.append(('V', f"{nickname} Присоединился"))
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"'{nickname}' Присоединился"))

    refresh_task = run_async(refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box))

    while True:
        data = await input_group("Новое сообщение", [
            input(placeholder="Сообщение", name="msg"),
            actions(name="cmd", buttons=["Отправить", {'label:': "Выйти", 'type': 'cancel'}])

        ], validate=lambda m: ('msg', "Введите текст сообщения") if m["cmd"] == "Отправить" and not m["msg"] else None)

        if data is None:
            break

        msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"{nickname} : {data['msg']}"))
        chat_msgs.append((nickname, data['msg']))

    # Выход
    refresh_task.close()

    online_users.remove(nickname)
    toast('Вы вышли из чата')
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f'V Пользователь {nickname} вышел'))
    chat_msgs.append(('V', f"Пользователь {nickname} вышел"))

    put_buttons(["Перезайти"], onclick=lambda btn: run_js('window.location.reload('))


async def refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box):
    global chat_msgs
    last_idx = len(chat_msgs)

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        for m in chat_msgs[last_idx:]:
            if m[0] != nickname:
                msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"{m[0]}: {m[1]}"))

        # remove expired
        if len(chat_msgs) > MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT:
            chat_msgs = chat_msgs[len(chat_msgs) // 2:]

        last_idx = len(chat_msgs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server(main, debug=True, port=1606, cdn=False)
```

Comment: Не добавляйте код/ошибки картинками, вставляйте это как текст.

Comment: Хорошо, исправил

Answer (score 0):

У вас в строчке

```py
actions(name="cmd", buttons=["Отправить", {'label:': "Выйти", 'type': 'cancel'}])
```

у второй кнопки поле называется не `label`, а `label:`. Если убрать двоеточие, то всё заработает :)
Если был полезен, отметьте, пожалуйста, ответ как правильный

Answer (score 0):

Код у меня запустился, единственное что поправил это **2** опечатки.

Опечатка в `'label:'` **->** `'label':`

Опечатка в скобках `'window.location.reload(')))` **->** `'window.location.reload()'))`

В коде выделил комментариями место исправлений:

```
from pywebio import start_server
from pywebio.input import *
from pywebio.output import *
from pywebio.session import run_async, run_js

import asyncio

chat_msgs = []
online_users = set()

MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT = 100


async def main():
    global chat_msgs

    put_markdown("## Добро пожаловать в Чат(Alpha 1)")

    msg_box = output()
    put_scrollable(msg_box, height=300, keep_bottom=True)

    nickname = await input("Войти в чат", reguired=True, placeholder="Ваше имя",
                           validate=lambda n: "Такой ник уже есть" if n in online_users or n == "V" else None)
    online_users.add(nickname)

    chat_msgs.append(('V', f"{nickname} Присоединился"))
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"'{nickname}' Присоединился"))

    refresh_task = run_async(refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box))

    while True:
        data = await input_group("Новое сообщение", [
            input(placeholder="Сообщение", name="msg"),
            # Опечатка в 'label:'
            actions(name="cmd", buttons=["Отправить", {'label': "Выйти", 'type': 'cancel'}])

        ], validate=lambda m: ('msg', "Введите текст сообщения") if m["cmd"] == "Отправить" and not m["msg"] else None)
        # ↑↑↑ !!! ↑↑↑

        if data is None:
            break

        msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"{nickname} : {data['msg']}"))
        chat_msgs.append((nickname, data['msg']))

    # Выход
    refresh_task.close()

    online_users.remove(nickname)
    toast('Вы вышли из чата')
    msg_box.append(put_markdown(f'V Пользователь {nickname} вышел'))
    chat_msgs.append(('V', f"Пользователь {nickname} вышел"))

    # Опечатка в скобках 'window.location.reload(')
    put_buttons(["Перезайти"], onclick=lambda btn: run_js('window.location.reload()'))
    # ↑↑↑ !!! ↑↑↑


async def refresh_msg(nickname, msg_box):
    global chat_msgs
    last_idx = len(chat_msgs)

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        for m in chat_msgs[last_idx:]:
            if m[0] != nickname:
                msg_box.append(put_markdown(f"{m[0]}: {m[1]}"))

        # remove expired
        if len(chat_msgs) > MAX_MESSAGES_COUNT:
            chat_msgs = chat_msgs[len(chat_msgs) // 2:]

        last_idx = len(chat_msgs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_server(main, debug=True, port=1606, cdn=False)
```